# Batch script to start the service in gap of 10 min

Tags: batch-file, service, time

Batch script to start the nodes in gap of 10 min OR time recorded from above step

I want to create a batch file which will start local jboss service as well as remote server in 10 mins gap and to start the another jboss server after 10 mins. Actually this services are all on different ip say jboss service1 at A ip, service2 at B ip, service3 at C ip and service4 at D ip. So i want to start this services on each server after 10 mins.

Comment: Thank you for this info. What is your question?

Comment: Batch script to start the jboss services in gap of 10 min. I am having 4 jboss service which i dnt want to start them at a same time. But they should start after 10 min of the service which is started.

Comment: actually this services are all on different ip say jboss service1 at A ip service2 at B ip service3 at C ip and service4 at D ip. So i want to start this services on each server after 10 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have two options to implement a "wait x seconds" in a bat file. If you are using Win7/Server 2000 or higher, you can use `timeout /t <TimeoutInSeconds>`.

The other way is to make your script ping localhost for x seconds which will result in waiting the desired amount of time: `ping -n <TimeoutInSeconds> localhost> nul`

While the first method doesn't work in all cases (some programs like Jenkins prohibit this kind of delay) the second should always do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I created a batch file for the same and it works very well. If any changes to be done please suggest.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74756/batch-script-to-start-the-service-in-a-gap-of-10-min